# There exists a random variable such that a sum of Poisson$(\lambda)$ of these random variables is Geometric

Tags: probability

Prove that for every $0<p<1$ there exists a probability mass function $p_1,p_2,\dots$ and $\lambda>0$ with $\sum_{i=1}^ZX_i\sim\text{Pessimistic Geometric}(p)$, where $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are iid., for $k\geq1$, $P\{X_i=k\}=p_k$ and $Z$ is an independent Poisson$(\lambda)$ random variable.

Here Pessimistic Geometric means that we count the number of failures before the first success. So if $Y\sim$ Pessimistic Geometric$(p)$, then $P\{Y=k\}=(1-p)^kp$.

Firstly, I'm not even sure I've totally understood the question, but so far my thoughts have been to try to do this using generating functions. Let the Poisson$(\lambda)$ variable have generating function $f_P(s)=e^{\lambda(s-1)}$, and the Pessimistic Geometric variable have generating function $f_G(s)=\frac p{1-s(1-p)}$. (I think these are correct). Then I know that I am looking for a probability mass function such that the generating function, $f(s)$, is such that
\begin{align*}
&f_P(f(s))=e^{\lambda(f(s)-1)}=\frac p{1-s(1-p)}=f_G(s)\\
\implies &\lambda(f(s)-1)=\log\left(\frac p{1-s(1-p)}\right)\\
\implies &f(s)=\frac1\lambda\log\left( \frac p{1-s(1-p)} \right)+1.
\end{align*}
So it seems like I have found the generating function I am looking for, but I don't think that this proves that this probability mass function exists, and I'm not sure if my workings are actually productive in this goal. Do I need to prove that this generating function is valid? Any help appreciated.

Comment: A probability generating function is valid if all the coefficients in its Taylor series are non-negative and $\lim\limits_{x \to 1^{-}} f(x)=1$.  The latter point is clearly true in your result

Comment: Thanks! What's the etiquette here, should I post your comment as an answer, or should you do it?

Comment: I have not given a full answer or checked your calculations.  You are free to answer yourself if you think you now do have a full answer